# Generating a random sequence of certain numbers in a deterministic time

Tags: c++, random

I have written the following piece of code to generate a random sequence of certain numbers {0,1,2,...,31}. It works fine, however, it cannot be guaranteed to complete within any finite amount of time; after any interval there is still only a certain (very high) probability that it will have completed.
Any suggestion for removing this issue?

```
int th;
vector<int> V2 = vector<int> (32,0);
for (int k=0;k<32;k++){

    do{
        th = rand() % 32;
    } while ( V2[th] == 0 );

    V2[th] = k;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "non-deterministic time?"  Also, WTF is that brace/indentation style you're using?

Comment: @RobertHarvey bounded over malicious values of `rand`, I figured.

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop? You create your vector and fill with value 0, then you have `while (V2[th]==0);`. You don't change any values before that loop, so `V2[th]==0` will always be true

Comment: Now that's a creative way to create a permutation. This is really bad code, and shouldn't be used in real world applications. But +1 for the idea... @wlyles: it actually works (at least in most cases)

Comment: Regardless of whether this is an infinite loop, I think I understand what the principle is. It runs in non-deterministic time because of how you select your random index. You always pick from between 0 and 31 for `th`, so there is no telling how many iterations of the `do while` loop will execute before you find an index with non-zero value, especially once most of the values are non-zero (in other words, as `k` gets bigger)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

And an actual implementation:

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, ....., 31 };
std::random_shuffle(a, a + 32);
```

or with vectors:

```
std::vector<int> v(a, a + 32); // from previous snippet
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
```

In addition, as usually, don't forget to seed the PRNG if you want true-ish random permutations.

Comment: If he wants to use `vector<int> V2`, then `std::random_shuffle(V2.begin(), V2.end());` would be more appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Populate a vector with the numbers between zero and 31, and then use a linear-time random shuffle algorithm, such as [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).